# Redux action is not being fired

Tags: redux, material-ui

Redux action changePictogramsKeyword is not being fired.

This is the file where I define my action and reducer (redux/module/keyword.js):

```
export const CHANGE_PICTOGRAMS_KEYWORD = 'CHANGE_PICTOGRAMS_KEYWORD'

export function changePictogramsKeyword (keyword) {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_PICTOGRAMS_KEYWORD,
    keyword
  }
}

// Updates error message to notify about the failed fetches.
export default function pictogramsKeyword (state = '', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_PICTOGRAMS_KEYWORD:
      return action.keyword
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

My root reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer as router } from 'react-router-redux'
import locale from './modules/locale'
import errorMessage from './modules/error'
import pictogramsKeyword from './modules/keyword'
export default combineReducers({
  locale,
  router,
  pictogramsKeyword,
  errorMessage
})
```

So with the devTools I can check that my initialState is as I expected from the rootReducer:

```
locale:"en"
router:{} 1 key
pictogramsKeyword:""
errorMessage:null
```

This is the code of the view where I connect to Redux Store. Component SearchBox is in charge of firing the action changePictogramsKeyword:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import SearchBox from 'components/SearchBox.js'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { changePictogramsKeyword } from 'redux/modules/keyword'


class SearchPictogramsView extends Component {

  handleDismissClick (e) {
    this.props.resetErrorMessage()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  render () {
    const { children, inputValue } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
          <SearchBox value={inputValue} onChange={changePictogramsKeyword} />
          {children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

SearchPictogramsView.propTypes = {
  inputValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node
}

function mapStateToProps (state, ownProps) {
  return {
    errorMessage: state.errorMessage,
    inputValue: state.pictogramsKeyword
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  resetErrorMessage, changePictogramsKeyword
})(SearchPictogramsView)
```

This is the code of the SearchBox component. AutoComplete is a material-ui component. onUpdateInput method gets fired everytime I press a key, however changePictogramsKeyword is not being fired (i see nothing through the dev tools)

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/lib/auto-complete'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/lib/raised-button'


class SearchBox extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleUpdateInput = this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this)
  }

  handleUpdateInput = (t) => {
    console.log(t)
    this.props.onChange(t)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <AutoComplete onUpdateInput={this.handleUpdateInput} searchText={this.props.value} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

SearchBox.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default SearchBox
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was really in the docs:

> If an object is passed, each function inside it will be assumed to be
>   a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but
>   with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be
>   invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props

When I wrote:

```
<SearchBox value={inputValue} onChange={changePictogramsKeyword} />
```

Now is:

```
<SearchBox value={inputValue} onChange={this.props.changePictogramsKeyword} />
```

So I really call the dispatch of the action and not just the action!

Answer (score 3):

Right now, your action only gets called, but not dispatched because you're not mapping the actions correctly in the `connect()` call. (see the [official documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#container-components) for more information)

In your `SearchPictogramsView`, change the `mapDispatchToProps` function of the `connect()` call to return an object with the wrapped functions:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, (dispatch) => {
  return {
    resetErrorMessage: () => dispatch(resetErrorMessage()),
    changePictogramsKeyword: () => dispatch(changePictogramsKeyword())
  };
})(SearchPictogramsView)
```

You can clean it up by making `mapDispatchToProps` its own function too:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    resetErrorMessage: () => dispatch(resetErrorMessage()),
    changePictogramsKeyword: () => dispatch(changePictogramsKeyword())
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchPictogramsView)
```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Your code doesn't solve the issue. I think it's also ok as I wrote it. My second parameter in the connect method is an object...and, from the docs: If an object is passed, each function inside it will be assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props

Comment: The url: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Comment: TIL, my bad. I didn't know that worked, glad you found the solution!